# Ссылка на скайп не работает

Tags: html, skype

Пытаюсь установить на сайт кнопку с переходом на скайп. Ссылку ставлю верную, 100 раз проверила. А открывает пустую вкладку `about:blank`. Почему это может быть и что нужно сделать?

Ставлю такую ссылку

```
<a href="skype:SkypeUser">SkypeUser</a>
```

только вместо SkypeUser свой скайп

Comment: приведите ваш код. интуитивно помощи вряд ли дождётесь

Comment: ставлю такую ссылку <a href="skype:SkypeUser">SkypeUser</a> только вместо SkypeUser свой скайп

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А скайп-то установлен?

Comment: `skype://SkypeUser`?

Comment: Да, конечно.  Пробовала с разных браузеров и разных компьютеров. И планшета.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ещё такой вариант: 
http://www.skype.com/en/create-contactme-buttons/

Пример:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_myskype_1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Skype.ui({
      "name": "call",
      "element": "SkypeButton_Call_myskype_1",
      "participants": ["здесь укажите ваш логин скайп"]
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую)

Comment: Тоже не помогло( Ничего не понимаю(

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы заставить Skype звонить нужно добавить `call`:

```
<a href="skype:username?call"></a>
```

Отправление сообщения в чат, добавить `chat`:

```
<a href="skype:username?chat"></a>
```

Пример:

```html
<a href="skype:echo123?call">Call</a> <br/>

<a href="skype:echo123?chat">Chat</a>
```

[источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/93655/)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, правильный ли логин скайпа. И проверьте этот вариант:

`<a href="skype:********?call">Skype to call my Skype username</a>`